# Replacing Text in MultiDimensional Array to another Text in another Multi Dimensional Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been struggling in finding solution for the following scenario,

I have following Multi Dimensional Array,

```
String [][] a1 ={{ New1 , d1, e1 },{ New2 , d2, e2 },{ New3 , d2, e1 },}; 

String [][] b1 ={{ d1, Re1 },{ d2, Re2 },}; 

String [][] c1 ={{ e1, 1 },{ e2, 2 },};
```

I want to replace the contents in the String Array a1 to be replaced with appropriate identifiers from string b1 and c1 and the following output should be obtained,

```
String [][] new ={{ New1 , Re1, 1 },{ New2 , Re2, 2 },{ New3 , Re2, 1 },};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would probably be to use a `Map` instead of a `String[][]` for `b1` and `c1`. You can build maps like this:

```
Map<String, String> b1Map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String[] entry : b1) {
    b1Map.put(entry[0], entry[1]);
}
// similarly for c1
```

(Alternatively, you could build the maps directly instead of first building the `b1` and `c1` arrays.) Then you could do something like this:

```
for (String[] item : a1) {
    item[1] = b1Map.get(item[1]);
    item[2] = c1Map.get(item[2]);
}
```

Comment: What if, the order of element in a1 changed :(

Comment: @SachinPasalkar - I don't see how that would affect anything. Each item's second entry is mapped to the look-up from the `b1` data and each item's third entry is mapped according to the `c1` data. These are associative (value-based) lookups, not by position in the `a1` array.

Comment: Though, fazy has this scenario. The solution does not look like generalized one.

Comment: @SachinPasalkar - The answer was targeted at Fazy's question, not at solving the general problem of how to do look-ups. This could be generalized in many different ways (more dimensions; different kinds of objects; missing map values; etc.). It would be pointless to try to write one code that tried to cover all possibilities, and it would make the answer incomprehensible. Let Fazy explain what generalization is needed (if any) and that can be addressed.

Comment: I have did the same after reading your suggestion but I have implemented using LinkedHashMap to retain insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want  to use collections or you need solve it without using collections, you can do something like the following code that solves your requirement with by handling the arrays

```
for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<b1.length;j++){
        if(b1[j][0].equals(a1[i][1])){
            a1[i][1]=b1[j][1];
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<c1.length;j++){
        if(c1[j][0].equals(a1[i][2])){
            a1[i][2]=c1[j][1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Emecas the solution was helpful.